# How to find out the count of one column in multiple group by using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `options` with the following data:

```
id|content|index| question_id
----------------------------
1 | yes   |  1  | 123
2 | no    |  2  | 123
3 | maybe |  1  | 123
4 | yeah  |  2  | 124
5 | yep   |  1  | 124
6 | nope  |  1  | 125
7 | no    |  2  | 125
8 | yessir|  1  | 125
```

Each option is mapped to an MCQ question on the question_id. There cannot be duplicated indexes for a question. 
I want to **find out the number of options with duplicate indexes against the same question_id**

Here's how I am trying to do it:

```
SELECT 
  count(index) as c, 
  question_id 
from options 
group by question_id, index having c > 1
```

However, I don't seem to get the result I am looking for.

I want to get the following rows called out:

```
id | content | index | question_id
-----------------------------------
3  | maybe   | 1     | 123
8  | yessir  | 1     | 125
```

Also, the following result set will help as well:

```
question_id | duplicates
-------------------------
123         | 2
125         | 2
```

Comment: Just to make things clearer, what is the expected result for the sample table you've provided?

Comment: A compound UNIQUE KEY on the `index` and `question_id` columns is advised to keep it clean in the future.

Comment: @Mureinik added expected result.

Comment: @Pred Cleaning up an existing database. Have added unique keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select question_id, sum(dups) dups from ( 
SELECT 
  question_id,
  option_index,
  count(option_index) dups
from options 
group by question_id, option_index
having count(option_index) > 1)
group by question_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  question_id, 
  count(index) as duplicates
from options 
group by question_id, option_index having count(index) > 1
```

use `count` function. Aliased column `c` is not available in `having` clause.